# Error in set NSString property from another class

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

i have a problem passing a string to another UIViewController and then open this UIViewController, this is what i do:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BroswerViewController : UIViewController

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *myBrowserView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * myString;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation BroswerViewController
@synthesize myBrowserView;
@synthesize myString;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

}
return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

myString = [myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite/%@",myString]];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[myBrowserView loadRequest:request];

}
```

class where i call it:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (!self.myBroserViewController) {
    self.myBroserViewController = [[[BroswerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BroswerViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}

[self.myBroserViewController setMyString:[NSString stringWithString:[stringArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myBroserViewController animated:YES];
}
```

ok, so i pass a string to the BrowseViewController class, and then open the browseviewcontroller class and open the url with the string i have passed, and the first time work always, then i return back and pass another string and open the view and the second time works random, and the third time never, and i always receive a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line

```
@synthesize myString;
```

i don't know what i wrong...

Comment: Can you post the code that populates stringArray?

Comment: I do this: stringArray addObject:@"string" and i display it in a table view and works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a couple of pointers to @Phillip Mills answer.

-On your init you should set myString to nil. This ensures that if it is released before being set somewhere else, it won't crash. Including if you use the setter which performs a release on it (you can release a nil reference).

-On your dealloc, you should release myString (unless you are using ARC).

-When you set it in viewWillAppear, you either need to do:

```
self.myString = [self.myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or

```
NSString *temp = myString;
[myString release];
myString = [[temp stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] retain];
```

they both accomplish the same thing. Using self is easier though.

-Finally, I would use copy instead of retain unless you have a very specific reason to use retain. This ensures something else doesn't change it on you.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have use your method, and seems all work fine, i have a question in the init i write self.myString = nil; or i have to do myString = nil; ?...and i have another question, about you i have to use also self.myBrowserView instead of myBrowserView?

Comment: In the init you set all your ivars to nil (including myBrowserView) without using the setter (self). So myString = nil; myBrowserView = nil; etc. Then in dealloc, [myString release]; [myBrowserView release]; etc.

Comment: You never *have* to use getter or setter (self.). When you READ the variable it makes no difference. When you WRITE the variable you must either use setter (self.myBrowserView = ...) *OR* manually release and retain ([myBroserView release]; myBrowserView = [xyz retain];) Easier to use self.myBrowserView when you WRITE to the variable, but either is fine.

Comment: last question, when i do this [myBrowserView loadRequest:request]; it's better to do [self.myBrowserView loadRequest:request]?

Comment: It doesn't matter. It's a READ so self.myBrowser will simply return the ivar myBrowser. You'll get the exact same result. Probably best to be consistent for readability, so if you use self.xyz for WRITES then use them for READS. As an aside, you should really understand how getters and setters work (which is what you are calling when you call self.xyz) if you are writing an app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...you know a book or a tutorial where i can read it?

Comment: No. I learned it on SO and using Google searches. Never read an Objective C book.

Answer (score 3):

Use `self.myString` rather than the plain variable when you reference it in `viewWillAppear:`.  You're not getting the effect of the retain attribute when you use the variable directly rather than property notation.

Answer (score 0):

Best practices tells us use copy instead of retain in cases like this.
That's why:

```
myString = [myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

changes the initial string too and next time you call this for already escaped string. That's why you get such weird behavior :)

Solution - change

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * myString;
```

ON

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * myString;
```

Using

> self.myString

will solve it too, but it's still not a good practice... if, for example, your method will look like this:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[self prepareUrl:self.myString]];
```

you still can catch very weird and hardly debugable artifacts.

Comment: Hmmm, changing the property to copy without calling self.myString in viewDidAppear will not solve his issue. And using self.myString is the best practice. Otherwise in viewDidAppear he will need to add an explicit release and copy on the ivar being accessed directly.

Comment: Changing retain to copy will solve the issue :) [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; will copy string by itself. So if you don't use it anymore - all is fine.
But using self.myString is still the best practice. And of course it's a good idea to use it if you don't have a good reason for not doing it.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are wrong. This line, myString = [myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; will always go out of scope at the end of the method and cause an error later. The issue is not in the property declaration. Retain would work just fine.

Comment: It depends what issue are we talking about. myString will be released. So what? What problem it will cause if this variable is not used in another place? If it used later and it's expected that it's still have a value - then yes. But initial problem was rewriting string given in [self.myBroserViewController setMyString:...].

Comment: Setting it was never the issue. What is causing the issue is he is changing myString in viewWillAppear without retaining/copying it. So the second time viewWillAppear is called (without reloading the view controller) it is trying to access myString to do the append and that variable has gone out scope because the first time it was not retained/copied. So he is indeed accessing it later...

Answer (score 0):

in my code i change the instance variable name within my synthesize.

Here is what your code could look like

```
@implementation BroswerViewController
@synthesize myBrowserViewh = _myBrowserViewh;
@synthesize myString = _myString;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

}
return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

self.myString = [self.myString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite/%@",self.myString]];
NSLog(@"%@",url);
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[myBrowserView loadRequest:request];

}
```

at that point you would be forced to use either

```
self.myString = @"";
```

or reference the instance variable via

```
_myString = @"";
```

this would let the compiler help you find bugs like this.